# What does TensorFlow's `conv2d_transpose()` operation do?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The documentation for the `conv2d_transpose()` operation does not clearly explain what it does:

> The transpose of conv2d.
>
> This operation is sometimes called "deconvolution" after
>   [Deconvolutional Networks](http://www.matthewzeiler.com/pubs/cvpr2010/cvpr2010.pdf), but is actually the transpose (gradient) of
>   conv2d rather than an actual deconvolution.

I went through the paper that the doc points to, but it did not help.

What does this operation do and what are examples of why you would want to use it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is the best explanation I've seen online how convolution transpose works is [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers).

I'll give my own short description.  It applies convolution with a fractional stride.  In other words spacing out the input values (with zeroes) to apply the filter over a region that's potentially smaller than the filter size.

As for the why one would want to use it.  It can be used as a sort of upsampling with learned weights as opposed to bilinear interpolation or some other fixed form of upsampling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Do you have any other questions about it? I can also update my answer or answer in the comments.

Comment: so in theory you can achieve the similar result by using the regular conv2d but first tiling the original image so it is bigger to begin with? And conv2d_transpose is just an easier way of doing pretty much the same thing?

Comment: Yes some implementations do exactly that. However I'm not sure that's the most efficient way of doing it. conv2d_transpose is defined to be what you described.

Comment: Any idea on how to use the equivalent function in tf-slim ? It asks you for kernel size and stride, but I tried everything, even fractional strides, there is no way to reproduce a larger image.

Comment: There are bugs with tf slim and another one of the packages they're trying to consolidate it all to contrib.  Just use the default tf.nn.conv2d_transpose() and ask this as a separate question on stack overflow or post an issue on the github page if you think there is something wrong with the implementation.

Answer (score 30):

Here's another viewpoint from the "gradients" perspective, i.e. why TensorFlow documentation says `conv2d_transpose()` is "actually the transpose (**gradient**) of conv2d rather than an actual deconvolution". **For more details on the actual computation done in `conv2d_transpose`, I would highly recommend [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf), starting from page 19.**

#### Four Related Functions

In `tf.nn`, there are 4 closely related and rather confusing functions for 2d convolution:

- `tf.nn.conv2d`
- `tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter`
- `tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_input`
- `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`

One sentence summary: **they are all just 2d convolutions**. Their differences are in their input arguments ordering, input rotation or transpose, strides (including fractional stride size), paddings and etc. With `tf.nn.conv2d` in hand, one can implement all of the 3 other ops by transforming inputs and changing the `conv2d` arguments.

#### Problem Settings

- Forward and backward computations:

```py
# forward
out = conv2d(x, w)

# backward, given d_out
=> find d_x?
=> find d_w?
```

In the forward computation, we compute the convolution of input image `x` with the filter `w`, and the result is `out`.
In the backward computation, assume we're given `d_out`, which is the gradient w.r.t. `out`. Our goal is to find `d_x` and `d_w`, which are the gradient w.r.t. `x` and `w` respectively.

For the ease of discussion, we assume:

- All stride size to be `1`
- All `in_channels` and `out_channels` are `1`
- Use `VALID` padding
- Odd number filter size, this avoids some asymmetric shape problem

#### Short Answer

Conceptually, with the assumptions above, we have the following relations:

```py
out = conv2d(x, w, padding='VALID')
d_x = conv2d(d_out, rot180(w), padding='FULL')
d_w = conv2d(x, d_out, padding='VALID')
```

Where `rot180` is a 2d matrix rotated 180 degrees (a left-right flip and a top-down flip), `FULL` means "apply filter wherever it partly overlaps with the input" (see [theano docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d)). Notes that *this is only valid with the above assumptions*, however, one can change the conv2d arguments to generalize it.

The key takeaways:

- The input gradient `d_x` is the convolution of the output gradient `d_out` and the weight `w`, with some modifications.
- The weight gradient `d_w` is the convolution of the input `x` and the output gradient `d_out`, with some modifications.

#### Long Answer

Now, let's give an actual working code example of how to use the 4 functions above to compute `d_x` and `d_w` given `d_out`. This shows how
`conv2d`,
`conv2d_backprop_filter`,
`conv2d_backprop_input`, and
`conv2d_transpose` are related to each other. 
[Please find the full scripts here](https://gist.github.com/yxlao/ef50416011b9587835ac752aa3ce3530).

**Computing `d_x` in 4 different ways:**

```py
# Method 1: TF's autodiff
d_x = tf.gradients(f, x)[0]

# Method 2: manually using conv2d
d_x_manual = tf.nn.conv2d(input=tf_pad_to_full_conv2d(d_out, w_size),
                          filter=tf_rot180(w),
                          strides=strides,
                          padding='VALID')

# Method 3: conv2d_backprop_input
d_x_backprop_input = tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_input(input_sizes=x_shape,
                                                 filter=w,
                                                 out_backprop=d_out,
                                                 strides=strides,
                                                 padding='VALID')

# Method 4: conv2d_transpose
d_x_transpose = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=d_out,
                                       filter=w,
                                       output_shape=x_shape,
                                       strides=strides,
                                       padding='VALID')
```

**Computing `d_w` in 3 different ways:**

```py
# Method 1: TF's autodiff
d_w = tf.gradients(f, w)[0]

# Method 2: manually using conv2d
d_w_manual = tf_NHWC_to_HWIO(tf.nn.conv2d(input=x,
                                          filter=tf_NHWC_to_HWIO(d_out),
                                          strides=strides,
                                          padding='VALID'))

# Method 3: conv2d_backprop_filter
d_w_backprop_filter = tf.nn.conv2d_backprop_filter(input=x,
                                                   filter_sizes=w_shape,
                                                   out_backprop=d_out,
                                                   strides=strides,
                                                   padding='VALID')
```

Please see the [full scripts](https://gist.github.com/yxlao/ef50416011b9587835ac752aa3ce3530) for the implementation of `tf_rot180`, `tf_pad_to_full_conv2d`, `tf_NHWC_to_HWIO`. In the scripts, we check that the final output values of different methods are the same; a numpy implementation is also available.

Comment: What is 'f' in the long-way example?  I believe you have a couple of typo errors: tf_rot180, etc.  Very informative!

Comment: @RobertLugg `f` is an arbitrary differentiable function (typically scalar value here) computed over `x`. `tf_rot180` is a custom function used for illustration purpose, please see the full scripts provided in the answer for more details.

Comment: To perform the forward pass, we multiply each single value of the input with the filter and get a the input scaled by the filter, hence we are up sampling. During backwards pass, we do the opposite, we convolve over the deltas from the next layer, right?

Answer (score 15):

conv2d_transpose() simply transposes the weights and flips them by 180 degrees. Then it applies the standard conv2d(). "Transposes" practically means that it changes the order of the "columns" in the weights tensor. Please check the example below.

Here there is an example that uses convolutions with stride=1 and padding='SAME'. It is a simple case but the same reasoning could be applied to the other cases.

Say we have:

- Input: MNIST image of 28x28x1, shape = [28,28,1]
- Convolutional layer: 32 filters of 7x7, weights shape = [7, 7, 1, 32], name = W_conv1

If we perform convolution of the input then the activations of the will have shape: [1,28,28,32].

```py
 activations = sess.run(h_conv1,feed_dict={x:np.reshape(image,[1,784])})
```

Where:

```py
 W_conv1 = weight_variable([7, 7, 1, 32])
 b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
 h_conv1 = conv2d(x, W_conv1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b_conv1
```

To obtain the "deconvolution" or "transposed convolution" we can use conv2d_transpose() on the convolution activations in this way:

```py
  deconv = conv2d_transpose(activations,W_conv1, output_shape=[1,28,28,1],padding='SAME')
```

OR using conv2d() we need to transpose and flip the weights:

```py
  transposed_weights = tf.transpose(W_conv1, perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])
```

Here we change the order of the "colums" from [0,1,2,3] to [0,1,3,2].So from [7, 7, 1, 32] we will obtain a tensor with shape=[7,7,32,1]. Then we flip the weights:

```py
  for i in range(n_filters):
      # Flip the weights by 180 degrees
      transposed_and_flipped_weights[:,:,i,0] =  sess.run(tf.reverse(transposed_weights[:,:,i,0], axis=[0, 1]))
```

Then we can compute the convolution with conv2d() as:

```py
  strides = [1,1,1,1]
  deconv = conv2d(activations,transposed_and_flipped_weights,strides=strides,padding='SAME')
```

And we will obtain the same result as before. Also the very same result can be obtained with conv2d_backprop_input() using:

```py
   deconv = conv2d_backprop_input([1,28,28,1],W_conv1,activations, strides=strides, padding='SAME')
```

The results are shown here:

[Test of the conv2d(), conv2d_tranposed() and conv2d_backprop_input()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJk7l.png)

We can see that the results are the same. To see it in a better way please check my code at:

https://github.com/simo23/conv2d_transpose

Here I replicate the output of the conv2d_transpose() function using the standard conv2d().

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Could you help me by explaining the implementation details of this layer? The forward pass is just scaling the values of the input by the filter weights. Depending on the stride, the scaling will overlap. During backwards it’s the same as a regular convoluting over the deltas, right?

Answer (score 5):

One application for conv2d_transpose is upscaling, here is an example that explains how it works:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1.5],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]]).reshape(1,3,3,1)

filt = np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4.0]]).reshape(2,2,1,1)

b = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(a,
                           filt,
                           output_shape=[1,6,6,1],
                           strides=[1,2,2,1],
                           padding='SAME')

print(tf.squeeze(b))

tf.Tensor(
[[0.  0.  0.  0.  1.5 3. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  4.5 6. ]
 [0.  0.  1.  2.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  3.  4.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]], shape=(6, 6), dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple explanation of what is going on in a special case that is used in [`U-Net`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) - that's one of the main use cases for transposed convolution.

We're interested in the following layer:

```
Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2))
```

What does this layer do **exactly**? Can we reproduce its work?

Here’s the **answer**:

- First of all the default padding in this case is valid. This means we have no padding.
- The size of the output will be 2 times bigger: if input (m, n), output will be (2m, 2n). Why is that? See the next point.
- Take the first element from the input and multiply by the filter weights with shape (2,2). Put it into the output. Take the next element, multiply and put in the output next to the first result without overlapping. Why is that? We have strides (2, 2).

Here's an example input and output (see details [here](https://medium.com/@ilyarudyak/transposed-convolution-3a4725872a9a?source=friends_link&sk=ecd7a3f8568cb0ac327920c9676d788e) and [here](https://gist.github.com/ilyarudyak/8fdec3a6111226a5123fa0988dc36303)):

```
In [15]: X.reshape(n, m)
Out[15]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
In [16]: y_resh
Out[16]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  7.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  9.,  9.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  7.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  9.,  9.],
       [10., 10., 11., 11., 12., 12., 13., 13., 14., 14.],
       [10., 10., 11., 11., 12., 12., 13., 13., 14., 14.]], dtype=float32)
```

This slide from Stanford's cs231n is useful for our question:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any linear transform, including convolution, can be represented as a matrix. A transpose convolution can be interpreted as transposing the convolution matrix before applying it. For example, consider the simple 1D convolution with kernel size of 3 and stride of 2.

[image]

If we transpose the convolution matrix and apply it to a 3 element vector we get the transpose convolution operation

[image]

Now at first, this doesn't look like a convolution operation anymore. But if we insert some zeros into the y vector first we can rewrite this equivalently as

[image]

This example demonstrates that the transpose of a strided convolution operator is equivalent to upsampling by a factor of the stride by inserting zeros, then adding some additional padding, and finally performing an unstrided (i.e. stride=1) convolution.

For higher dimensional transpose convolutions, the same upsampling-by-inserting-zeros method is applied to each dimensions before performing an unstrided convolution.